# Find the Jordan form, I'm stuck with some point

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

*$A$ is a $7\times7$ **invertible** matrix* , above the complex field.

$\operatorname{rank}(A-I) = 3$, and $A^3 = A$ . I need to find the Jordan form of $A$.

I'm stuck with some point: $A$ is **invertible** iff **zero is not an eigenvalue**, but by $A^3=A$ I can conclude that $A^3-A=0$ and therefore the characteristic polynomial is $t^3-t = t(t^2-1)$ but then **zero is an eigenvalue!** what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The only thing  you know is that $\;A\;$ is a zero of $\;x^3-x=x(x^2-1)\;$ **and** since $\;A\;$ is invertible and thus zero is *not* one of its eigenvalues, then...what??

Comment: However, $\operatorname{rank} (A - 3I) = 3$ can't be if $A^3 = A$. Was it $\operatorname{rank}(A-I) = 3$?

Comment: I know that $t(t^2-1)$ is some polynomial that A is a root of, so t must appear in the characteristic polynomial too, no?

Comment: @DanielFischer yes my apologies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $A$ is invertible then
$$A^3=A\iff A^2=I$$
so the polynomial with simple roots $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$ annihilates $A$ so $A$ is a diagonalizable matrix. Now since $\mathrm{rank}(A-I)=3$ so $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with multiplicity $4$ and then $-1$ is an eigenvalue with multiplicity $3$.

Comment: how do you know $(x-1)(x+1)$ is the minimal polynomial? maybe its just $(x+1)$ or $(x-1)$

Comment: If $x-1$ is the minimal polynomial then $A=I$ which isn't the case.

Comment: Nicely said, and straight to the point. +